# Тире зависит от смысла?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте уважаемые.
"На него не смотри()на меня смотри".

Здесь,как я понимаю,запятая ставится когда нет акцентирования на второй части предложения? А когда есть акцентирование,ставится тире?
Или я не прав?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё проще: в бессоюзном сложном предложении ставится тире, если части предложения противопоставлены друг другу, то есть когда можно вставить союз "а": На него не смотри - (а) на меня смотри"